# Read non-duplicate values from text file into collection

Tags: excel, vba, duplicates, text-files, userform

I am having difficulty populating a collection with unique values from a large text file from which I'm reading.  I tried reading all the values into the collection and then deleting duplicates but the code I used to do this takes a long time to run.  I keep reading about identifying collection objects with unique "keys" but I'm unsure how to incorporate this into the code I have and into what I'd like to accomplish.  Below is the current code I have:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    'Declare variables
    Const CMMData As String = "\\ATSTORE01\CMMData\21064D\21064D-OP400.dat"
    Dim strSN As New Collection
    Dim strSet As New Collection
    Dim strUniqueSet As New Collection
    Dim strFF As New Collection
    Dim strVHCC As New Collection
    Dim strVHCCMID As New Collection
    Dim strVHCVMID As New Collection
    Dim strVHCV As New Collection
    Dim strHWCC As New Collection
    Dim strHWCCMID As New Collection
    Dim strHWCVMID As New Collection
    Dim strHWCV As New Collection
    Dim LineData As String
    Dim SplitData() As String
    Dim LineIter As Long
    Dim UniqueSet As Variant
    Dim UniqueSet1 As Variant
    'Populate Set Number Listbox
    LineIter = 0
    With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        With .OpenTextFile(CMMData, ForReading)
            Do Until .AtEndOfStream
                LineIter = LineIter + 1
                If LineIter <= 4 Then
                    .SkipLine
                Else
                    LineData = .ReadLine
                    SplitData = Split(LineData, ",")
                    'Extracting Serial Number
                    strSN.Add SplitData(0)
                    'Extracting Set Number
                    strSet.Add SplitData(1)
                    'Extracting Unique Set Number
                    strUniqueSet.Add SplitData(1)  'This is where I'd like to very cleanly extract only unique, non-duplicate set numbers into this particular collection.
                    'Extracting Final Flow Area
                    strFF.Add SplitData(14)
                    'Extracting /V/ To Hook CC
                    strVHCC.Add SplitData(96)
                    'Extracting /V/ To Hook CC Mid
                    strVHCCMID.Add SplitData(97)
                    'Extracting /V/ To Hook CV Mid
                    strVHCVMID.Add SplitData(98)
                    'Extracting /V/ To Hook CV
                    strVHCV.Add SplitData(99)
                    'Extracting Hook Width CC
                    strVHCV.Add SplitData(134)
                    'Extracting Hook Width CC Mid
                    strVHCV.Add SplitData(135)
                    'Extracting Hook Width CV Mid
                    strVHCV.Add SplitData(136)
                    'Extracting Hook Width CV
                    strVHCV.Add SplitData(137)
                    'Set_Select.AddItem SplitData(1)
                End If
            Loop
            .Close
        End With
        'Below is the code I was using to remove the duplicate entries from the strUniqueSet collection
        For UniqueSet = strUniqueSet.Count To 2 Step -1
            For UniqueSet1 = (UniqueSet - 1) To 1 Step -1
                On Error GoTo DisplayUniqueSet
                If strUniqueSet.Item(UniqueSet) = strUniqueSet.Item(UniqueSet1) Then
                    strUniqueSet.Remove (UniqueSet)
                Else
                    Set_Select.AddItem strUniqueSet(UniqueSet)
                End If
            Next UniqueSet1
        Next UniqueSet
    End With
    Exit Sub
DisplayUniqueSet:
    MsgBox UniqueSet
End Sub
```

The ultimate intent of this section of code is to populate a listbox with the values from the strUniqueSet collection.  The user would then select a non-duplicate set number, and the program would then extract from the other collections all values correlating to that selected set number.

I greatly appreciate the help.

Comment: Look up Dictionaries. Collections do not require unique keys so Dictionaries which do would give a better match for your requirement.  Also Dictionaries are faster with large numbers of records becaused they are accessed by hashed key while Collections are accessed sequencially from the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Collections and Dictionaries can be slow, in my experience, especially if you multiple objects in the same code.  I would suggest loading the values into an multi-dimensional array and looping the array first to see if the values are there, and only adding if it's not. Then you can grab the information from the array when the user selects the non-duplicate number by looping the array again.

See code below. Note that it will produce multiple array elements that are essentially blank the current way its written.

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    Const CMMData As String = "\\ATSTORE01\CMMData\21064D\21064D-OP400.dat"
    Dim LineData As String
    Dim SplitData() As String
    Dim LineIter As Long
    Dim UniqueSet As Variant
    Dim UniqueSet1 As Variant

    Dim myArray() As String
    ReDim myArray(10, 0)


    LineIter = 0
    With New Scripting.FileSystemObject
        With .OpenTextFile(CMMData, ForReading)
            Do Until .AtEndOfStream

                LineIter = LineIter + 1

                ReDim Preserve myArray(10, LineIter)

                If LineIter <= 4 Then
                    myArray(1,LineIter) = "empty" & LineIter
                    .SkipLine
                Else

                    LineData = .ReadLine
                    SplitData = Split(LineData, ",")

                    Dim x As Long, bFound As Boolean

                    bFound = False
                    For x = LBound(myArray) To UBound(myArray)

                        If myArray(1, x) = SplitData(1) Then 'look if Set already exists
                            bFound = True
                            Exit For
                        End If

                    Next

                    If Not bFound Then 'if its not in array already, then add it

                        myArray(0, LineIter) = SplitData(0)
                        myArray(1, LineIter) = SplitData(1)
                        myArray(2, LineIter) = SplitData(14)
                        myArray(3, LineIter) = SplitData(96)
                        myArray(4, LineIter) = SplitData(97)
                        myArray(5, LineIter) = SplitData(98)
                        myArray(6, LineIter) = SplitData(99)
                        myArray(7, LineIter) = SplitData(134)
                        myArray(8, LineIter) = SplitData(135)
                        myArray(9, LineIter) = SplitData(136)
                        myArray(10, LineIter) = SplitData(137)

                    Else

                        myArray(1, LineIter) = "empty" & LineIter

                    End If

                End If

            Loop
            .Close
        End With

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: I am getting a "Subscript Out Of Range" error when I use this code.

Comment: on what line? It's possible I didn't refactor it fully correctly.

Comment: The error seems to be stemming from the declaration of myArray()

Comment: Sorry, I didn't realize the `ReDim Preserve` only worked on the last dimension in the array. I have edited the code. Please try again. so, now the first dimension holds all the details, and the 2nd dimension holds the "key".

Comment: The issue actually seems to stem from the code for the For Loop for the condition when bFound = True.  I'm still getting a Subscript Out Of Range error.

Comment: `ReDim Preserve` has to: (1) find space for the new larger array; (2) copy data from the old array; (3) initialise the new rows and (4) release the old array for garbage collection. It become very slow if used too often. Never increase array size one row at a time since this speeds progress to the slow down.

Comment: I have achieved success in two ways. (1) Have two passes of the data. In pass 1, count the number of rows required in the array. Size the array(s) as necessary. In pass 2, collect and process the data. (2) Have an index which is the next available free row in the array. When that index reaches the upper bound, use ReDim Preserve to add a large number (for example 1,000) of new rows.

Comment: @TonyDallimore - I am unfortunately still quite new to dealing with array and collection code.  If you would please provide some code showing your explanation, that would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you.

Comment: @ScottHoltzman - When I error-proofed the code, I discovered that the issue is that myArray(1,x) isn't getting populated and a Subscript Out Of Range error is consequently occurring because VBA is trying to equate an actual element in SplitData(1) to a blank value in SplitArray(1,x).  So, since I only want to fill myArray(1,x) with a non-duplicate element, how do I then provide an element into myArray (1,x) for comparison?  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I was thinking about that yesterday actually ...  good that you discovered that. I put in what I think may be a quick fix that will basically feel at least one of element in the array for each line, so there is always there. This is by no means ideal, still. But it will get you started. If I have time, I will refactor for a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 0):

Having studied your code, I do not think either collections or dictionaries are appropriate.  I have provided an answer which is how I would tackle your requirement.  I will add something on collections and dictionaries if you ask but I suspect this answer contains enough for you to study for the moment.

First I needed some test data.  Starting with an empty worksheet, I filled rows 1 to 10001 and columns 1 to 155 with unique values. I set column B to repeats of the values “A” to “Z”.  I exported that data as a CSV file named “Import.csv”.

Do not reinvent the wheel.  Excel has a perfectly adequate routine for importing a CSV file so there should be no need to code your own routine in VBA.  I rarely work with CSV files so do not remember the VBA syntax of the statements necessary to call the import routine.  I switched on the macro recorder, imported the CSV file (except for the first 4 lines) and switched off the macro recorder.  I tidied the macro recorder’s code to form the first part of my routine.

The macro recorder creates syntactically correct code but not good-practice code.  It doesn’t know your objectives so records exactly what you do as you do it.  I doubt you have 155 columns and you may wish to specify a format other than “General” for some columns.  You will have to redo the manual import with your data and tidy up the code the way I did.

The start of the code recorded for me was:

```
With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
    "TEXT;C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Import.csv", Destination:=Range("A1"))
    .Name = "Import"
```

I tidied this to get:

```
With WshtIn
.Cells.EntireRow.Delete         ' Delete existing content
  With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & _
                                    "\Import.csv", Destination:=.Range("A1"))
    .Name = "DataIn"
```

It is best to avoid use of the `ActiveSheet`.  I have specified a variable of type Worksheet, `WshtIn`, and have set it to the worksheet I wish to use.

The original connection string `TEXT;C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\Import.csv` is a single literal which I have replaced with an expression.

I almost always have my workbooks and the files they process in the same folder.  `ActiveWorkbook.Path` gives me the folder of my workbook.  By using this as my folder name, I can move the files to a new folder and the code still works.

`Destination:=Range("A1")` relies on the destination being within the `ActiveSheet`. The addition of a period at the beginning to create `.Destination:=Range("A1")`means the destination is within the worksheet defined by `With WshtIn`.

Lastly I have replaced `.Name = "Import"` by `.Name = "DataIn"` because I do not want the worksheet named for the CSV file.

The remaining code I have kept unchanged except for an extra `End With` at the end. As I said, you will have to replace my import code with code appropriate to your needs.  I suggest you import your CSV file with the macro recorder switched on.  Start a new macro based on the recorded code and play with it until you get macro to import the CSV just as you wish before looking at the next bit on my code.

You only want 11 columns of this CSV file.  So I have coded a loop that moves those 11 columns to a new worksheet, “DataKeep”.  The macro recorder does not do loops so would not be any help; you have to know the relevant syntax to code this.  I have used an array to define the columns to be moved.  I believe I have specified the columns correctly but you will need to check.  Probably best to add this code to your macro and get it right before moving on.

Worksheet “DataKeep” contains just the data you want.  I discarded the first 4 rows when I imported it and I only kept the column of interest.  Further down the routine you will find:

```
Data = .Range(…).Value
```

This loads the contents of the range into Data as a two dimensional array.  For most arrays, the convention is to have columns as the first dimension and rows as the second so `ReDim Preserve` can be used to increase the number of rows.  However, for arrays loaded from a worksheet or being prepared for downloading to a worksheet, the first dimension is for rows and the second is for columns.  This is helpful because it matches the syntax for a cell: `Cells(RowNumber, ColNumber).`

At the end of my macro I show how to access Data by displaying the first 20 rows.  This is not the list of collections you have in your code but I believe you will find an array more convenient.

The easiest way of getting a list of the unique values for the Set column is to use the advanced autofilter.  Again this is something I do not use very frequently and I do not have the correct syntax at my finger tips.  I used the macro recorder to capture the necessary code as I created a list of unique sets.  I copied the visible cells within that list of as an array to `UniqueSets`.  I believe my code will meet your requirements without amendment but you might wish to try creating this code with the macro recorder as an training exercise.

Work through my code, updating it as necessary, and study how I achieved the effects I have.  There are more instructions and explanations within the code.  Come back with questions as necessary but, the more you can understand on your own, the faster you will develop.

```
Option Explicit

  '   Constants allow you to name columns rather than use numbers or letters that
  ' may change. If the position of a column changes, amend the Const statement and
  ' the code is fully updated.  Searching code for the old column number so it can
  ' be updated to the new can be a nightmare.
  '   I have guessed names for the columns based on your code. Change as necessary.
  '   ColKeepSet is the only one I use.
  Const ColKeepSN As Long = 1
  Const ColKeepSet As Long = 2
  Const ColKeepFF As Long = 3
  Const ColKeepVHCC As Long = 4
  Const ColKeepVHCCMID As Long = 5
  Const ColKeepVHCVMID As Long = 6
  Const ColKeepVHCV1 As Long = 7
  Const ColKeepVHCV2 As Long = 8
  Const ColKeepVHCV3 As Long = 9
  Const ColKeepVHCV4 As Long = 10
  Const ColKeepVHCV5 As Long = 11
Sub Import()

  Dim ColInCrnt As Variant
  Dim ColKeepCrnt As Long
  Dim ColKeepLast As Long
  Dim ColWidths() As Long
  Dim Data As Variant
  Dim Headings As Variant
  Dim RngFilter As Range
  Dim RngUnique As Range
  Dim RowKeepCrnt As Long
  Dim RowKeepLast As Long
  Dim RowKeepSetLast As Long
  Dim RowUnqCrnt As Long
  Dim UniqueSets As Variant
  Dim WshtIn As Worksheet
  Dim WshtKeep As Worksheet

  ' Change the names of the worksheets as necessary
  Set WshtIn = Worksheets("DataIn")
  Set WshtKeep = Worksheets("DataKeep")

  ' Import the CSV file. Change "Import.csv" to your filename. Change folder if necessary.
  With WshtIn
    .Cells.EntireRow.Delete         ' Delete existing content
    With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Import.csv", Destination:=.Range("A1"))
      .Name = "DataIn"
      .FieldNames = True
      .RowNumbers = False
      .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
      .PreserveFormatting = True
      .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
      .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
      .SavePassword = False
      .SaveData = True
      .AdjustColumnWidth = True
      .RefreshPeriod = 0
      .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
      .TextFilePlatform = 850
      .TextFileStartRow = 5
      .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
      .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
      .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
      .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
      .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
      .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
      .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
      .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, _
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With
  End With

  ' Copy the required columns from worksheet "DataIn" to "DataKeep"
  WshtKeep.Rows.Delete      ' Discard any reviosu data
  ColKeepCrnt = 1
  For Each ColInCrnt In Array(1, 2, 15, 97, 98, 99, 100, 135, 136, 137, 138)
    WshtIn.Columns(ColInCrnt).Copy Destination:=WshtKeep.Cells(1, ColKeepCrnt)
    ColKeepCrnt = ColKeepCrnt + 1
  Next

  ' Delete contents of Worksheet "DataIn" which are no longer needed
  WshtIn.Rows.Delete

  With WshtKeep

    RowKeepSetLast = .Cells(Rows.Count, ColKeepSet).End(xlUp).Row
    Set RngFilter = .Range(.Cells(1, ColKeepSet), _
                           .Cells(RowKeepSetLast, ColKeepSet))

    .Columns(ColKeepSet).AutoFilter
    RngFilter.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True

    ' One copy of each unqiue set will be visible.  In addition row 1 will be visible
    ' because Excel assumes it is a header row.

    Set RngUnique = .Range(.Cells(2, ColKeepSet), _
                           .Cells(RowKeepSetLast, ColKeepSet)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

    Debug.Print RngUnique.Address
    UniqueSets = RngUnique.Value

    .Columns(ColKeepSet).AutoFilter     ' Clear

    '   There are various methods of finding the last used row and column. Above I have used
    ' .End(xlUp) which is the easiest method of finding the last row of a column. Your data
    ' is almost certainly rectangular so I could have assumed that the last row of the Set
    ' column is the last row of all columns. Since I have saved selected columns, I could
    ' have deduced the last column from that.  However, I have decided to show a different
    ' technique.
    '   Both of the following statements use Find to locate the last cell contaning a value.
    ' Both start the search "After" cell A1 and the search direction is "xlPrevious".
    ' The previous cell from A1 is the bottom, right cell so both searches got up and across
    ' until they find a cell with a value. In the first the search order is "xlByRows" and
    ' the second it is "xlByColumns". So the first find the first row with a value and the
    ' second the first column with a value. If the data is arranged in a neat rectangle, the
    ' last row and the last column will be for the same cell. But if the data is not a neat
    ' rectangle these statements will still the correct results.
    RowKeepLast = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    ColKeepLast = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                              SearchOrder:=xlByColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Column

    Data = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), _
                  .Cells(RowKeepLast, ColKeepLast)).Value

  End With

  ' Output all the unique sets
  Debug.Print "Unique Sets"
  For RowUnqCrnt = 1 To UBound(UniqueSets, 1)
    Debug.Print UniqueSets(RowUnqCrnt, 1)
  Next

  ' Output the first 20 rows of the data

  ' This will ReDim Headings as an array with a lower bound of 0
  Headings = VBA.Array("SN", "Set", "FF", "VHCC", "VHCCMID", "VHCVMID", _
                       "VHCV1", "VHCV2", "VHCV3", "VHCV4", "VHCV5")

  ReDim ColWidths(1 To UBound(Data, 2))

  ' Caluclate maximum width of each column
  For ColKeepCrnt = 1 To UBound(Data, 2)
    ColWidths(ColKeepCrnt) = Len(Headings(ColKeepCrnt - 1))
  Next
  For RowKeepCrnt = 1 To 20         ' Replace 20 by Ubound(Data, 1) to include all rows
    For ColKeepCrnt = 1 To ColKeepLast
      If ColWidths(ColKeepCrnt) < Len(Data(RowKeepCrnt, ColKeepCrnt)) Then
        ColWidths(ColKeepCrnt) = Len(Data(RowKeepCrnt, ColKeepCrnt))
      End If
    Next
  Next

  ' Output data
  Debug.Print "Data"
  Debug.Print "|";
  For ColKeepCrnt = 1 To ColKeepLast
    Debug.Print PadR(Headings(ColKeepCrnt - 1), ColWidths(ColKeepCrnt)) & "|";
  Next
  Debug.Print
  For RowKeepCrnt = 1 To 20
    Debug.Print "|";
    For ColKeepCrnt = 1 To ColKeepLast
      Debug.Print PadR(Data(RowKeepCrnt, ColKeepCrnt), ColWidths(ColKeepCrnt)) & "|";
    Next
    Debug.Print
  Next

End Sub
Function PadR(ByVal Str As String, ByVal PadLen As Long) As String

  If Len(Str) >= PadLen Then
    ' Do not truncate over length strings
    PadR = Str
  Else
    PadR = Left$(Str & Space(PadLen), PadLen)
  End If

End Function
```